# How to get the text after a span using jquery (multiple span)

Tags: jquery

I have this html code and I was wondering how to get the text after span
I tried using different methods and none worked.

```html
<div id="nowplaying">
    <div class="art200-left fixed-height">
        <img class="art200" alt="Album Art" src="https://www.animenfo.com/radio/albumart/PCCA-02442.jpg" id="nowplaying_albumart" albumart class="albumart" hotkey="alt+=" />
        <div class="float-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span6"> <span class="text-semibold">Artist:</span>  <span data-search-artist>Ueto Aya</span>
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Title:</span> Namida no Niji
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Album:</span>  <span data-search-album>Namida no Niji/SAVE ME</span> (2007)
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Album Type:</span> Theme Song Single
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Series:</span>  <span class="seriestag">Hotelier</span>
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Genre(s):</span> Jdorama
                    <br/>
                </div>
                <div class="span6"> <span class="text-semibold">Duration:</span>  <span id="np_timer" rel="214">3:34</span> / <span id="np_time" rel="265">4:25</span>
                    <br/> <span class="text-semibold">Rating:</span> 5.95 / 10 (234 rates)
                    <br/>
```

I'm trying to get the text `Namida no Niji`, `Theme Song Single` and other text after a span.

Comment: There is a `nextSibling` property in JS. You can use that to get the text node.

Comment: Why not restructure your HTML to make this easier on yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elemBefore = $('span.text-semibold').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(/Title:/);
    }),
    relatives = elemBefore.parent().contents(),
    index = relatives.index(elemBefore);
var after = relatives.eq(index+1).text();
```

`elemBefore` is assigned the element relative to which you want the next node.
`relatives` is assigned a selector of all of the nodes with the same parent including itself.
`index` is assigned the index of `elemBefore` within `relatives`.
`after` grabs the text your test case is looking for.

The key to this is the `contents` jquery method. It returns all of the child nodes (including text nodes). The `eq` method is used to get the node after by index.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for!. The other one posted by John is also good!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `nextSibling` and it's corresponding `nodeValue`to get the text of the element which is located after the `span`.

**Code snippets:**

```
var spans = $("div.span6 br").next("span.text-semibold"),
    i = 0, spansLength = spans.length,arr = [];      
while (i < spansLength) {
    if (spans[i].nextSibling.nodeValue != "  ")
    arr[i] = spans[i].nextSibling.nodeValue;
    i++;
}
```

**arr** variable holds all the text values that you need.

Hope this helps you...